# MapBox html marker

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I have an html marker, and I want to have a button inside, to delete this marker

```
const PoiHtml = (poi: PointOfInterest) =>
        `<h3>${poi.name}</h3>
        <button>delete</button>`

const source = map.getSource(`marker-${poi.id}`) as any;
source.setData({
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': [
                {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'properties': {
                        'description': PoiHtml(poi),
                        'icon': 'theatre'
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

How can I get the event of clicked delete button ?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to make this, but one probably the simplest is to use HTML `onclick` event. you only need to modify your string for `PoiHtml` adding an `onclick` attibute with the value of the event handler.

I have created a quick fiddle on [how to add an event to a marker popup](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/f1qo4uwy/26/). Every time you click the button, the console will log `"deleted"` through the event

Here is the relevant code:

```
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'PUT HERE YOUR TOKEN';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [-73.99594, 40.680975],
      zoom: 17
    });


    map.on('style.load', function() {

      map.on('click', function(e) {
        let l = map.getStyle().layers;

        var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
          layers: ['poi-label', 'transit-label', 'landuse', 'national-park']
        });

        let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
            draggable: true
          })
          .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
          .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
              offset: 25
            }) // add popups
            .setHTML('<h3>Actions</h3><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btnDelete" onclick="clicked()" >delete</button>'));
        marker.addTo(map);
        marker.togglePopup();
      });

    });

    function clicked() {
      console.log("deleted");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunatly i got " Uncaught ReferenceError: clicked is not defined" maybe it's because i'm on react ?

Comment: If you could provide a fiddle or codepen with a minimal reproducible sample it would be easier. What I know about react is that events definition has a different syntax but it’s not very different